# Calling notes URL from a web page with query string parameters in URL

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, hcl-notes, ibm-domino

We have a web page with links to Notes client. We can open existing document easily or create a new one with syntax: notes://localhost/__A92574C800517FC7.nsf/company?OpenForm Is there a way how to, in notes client, ready query string parameters provided in URL like this: notes://localhost/__A92574C800517FC7.nsf/company?OpenForm&param1=value . We tried a common ways like using @UrlQueryString("param1") in the form but no luck. Is there any otheroption for doing this?

Comment: Can you try running an agent?  I don't know if this works in the client or is a server only option.  Details here:  http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/DOMM-4Q8G7N/

Comment: Call "notes:// ... "URL: with ?OpenAgent ... says in LN client "Operation not currently implemented"

Comment: I don't think query strings are supported with notes:// URLs.. Most likely, the only way you have available for communicating data to the form you are opening is by writing it to something that a queryOpen script in the form knows how to read. E.g., environment varialbes in notes.ini or some other file that the code can read.

Answer (score 0):

Could you see what happens (not sure here...) when you add a text-field xyz to the form and use a notes-url like notes://localhost/__A92574C800517FC7.nsf/company?OpenForm&xyz=something ?

Comment: Tried that already, we couldn't find a way how to read such query string parameter on Ln client side. We tried to uss approach used for common web development like "query_string" field or @UrlQueryString("param1") formula but no way ...

Comment: David, were you able to solve your problem? I'm now in exactly the same situation as you, discovered my own suggestion above (doesn't work), and what now? Any luck on your side??

Comment: We resolved it, but not by reading query string params. It's really not possible. What we have done is, that we create temporary document with values we need to forward, then we open this document using this notes://localhost/...   URL, and on PostOpen event we open another document based on information stored in this tmp doc, and we close/delete this tmp document. We use this flow successfully for several months now ...

Comment: Thx! I'm afraid that won't work for me: I want to send a notes-link by mail, where the target document could be in any of several databases. The link should always work. I added an AHA idea: https://domino-ideas.hcltechsw.com/ideas/DDXP-I-1048